# Is there any way to set TTL (expiration) for Room record in Android?

Tags: android, android-room

I'm trying to implement an offline cache using Room instead of OkHttp Cache. The cache result of each request is only valid for short time like 30 mins.

Here is the flow:

1. The app first load data from database
2. If the data is available and not expired, display it to user.
   If not:
3. Load data from API
4. Refresh cache with new expiration time(or time stamp)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use room database as a cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57117162/how-to-use-room-database-as-a-cache)

Comment: @Abhishek Dutt, I want to create a currency exchange app. The app first check against cache or local data source. If the cache has not expired then display the data to user. If not, clear cache, get data from server and refresh cache.

Comment: @nonamelogger Mine is similar to the first implementation of that answer"A common approach to using Room (or any caching) would be to either load initial data from the database, display this to the user, perform an api call, update the cache and display this updated data from the api" BUT with expiration meaning only choose to display to user the data from database IF AND ONLY IF it is not expired yet.

Comment: @aLe Oaky. I would suggest you to go around the concept of coroutines, might help you with this. It is still unclear that what does `expired` means in your problem. Is this a pre-defined term or related to the server. Once you define `expire` one can start implementing the solution.

Comment: @AbhishekDutt expiration is defined in client(Android). I don't have control over the external API. Since I'm more familiar with TTL in NoSQL like Redis, Cassandra or Scylla in backend I thought Room have similar mechanism. I will add timestamp and do manual check against system time then. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **NO** automated or an in-built way to handle the time expiration in Room Persistence Library(Room Database). One has to handle it manually.

One way to do that is create two columns in the table:

1. `createdDate`
2. `lastUpDatedDate`

Whenever there is an Insert or an Update operation, the `lastUpDatedDate` column should be updated with the current timestamp.

The next time a `Read` operation happens, limit it by the `TTL`(defined in Android Client) and whenever there is `Write` operation, update the `TTL`.

This is one way of doing it. Other ways can include implementing threads(or [Couroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html), if Kotlin is used in code base).